# Split space from string not working in Kotlin

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, kotlin-extension

Anyone wonder this ? Splitting **SPACE (" ")** in kotlin is not working, i tried with different regex codes but is not working at all.

Tried with this :

```
value.split("\\s")[0];
value.split("\\s+")[0];
value.split("\\s++")[0];
```

Then i came up with solution -> Create java constant class which contains this function and returns string array to your kotlin class.

Is there any other solution for this problem where we can directly achieve this thing?

**Solution :** As @Edson Menegatti said :

**KOTLIN Specific : WORKING**

```
values.split("\\s".toRegex())[0]
```

Many people suggested this solution :  **NOT WORKING**

```
values.split(" ")[0]
```

But in my case it's **not working**.

Comment: you don't need semicolon, btw.

Comment: its a java code actually. :P i mentioned that i came up with this solution. ;)

Answer (score 57, accepted):

Here's an issue between the Java and Kotlin implementation of `String.split`.

While the Java implementation does accept a regex string, the Kotlin one does not. For it to work, you need to provide an actual `Regex` object.

To do so, you would update your code as follows:

```
value.split("\\s".toRegex())[0]
```

Also, as @Thomas suggested, you can just use the regular space character to split your string with:

```
value.split(" ")[0]
```

Final point, if you're only using the first element of the split list, you might want to consider using `first()` instead of `[0]` - for better readability - and setting the limit parameter to 2 - for better performance.

Comment: This is so stupid. I get why but this doesn't make it easy to go from java -> kotlin.

Answer (score 13):

You should use:

> .toRegex()

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
        val str = "Kotlin com"
        
        val separate1 = str.split("\\s".toRegex())[0]
        println(separate1) // ------------------> Kotlin
}
```

**OR**

You can also use `.split(" ")[0]` to achieve result. Like

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
            val str = "Kotlin com"
            
            val separate1 = str.split(" ")[0]
            println(separate1) // ----------> Kotlin
}
```

Answer (score 5):

[`String#split`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.text/split.html) (actually `CharSequence#split`) can take either a regular expression, or just a string which is interpreted literally. So:

```
value.split(" ")[0]
```

does what you want.

If you're only using the first element, it's more efficient to also pass `limit = 2`. Or, even better, use [`substringBefore`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.text/substring-before.html).

Comment: Your assertion is it not true, String.split() can also take a regex, a pattern...

Comment: Thanks @AlexTa, edited. I failed to scroll down far enough.

Comment: No this thing is not working in kotlin, i already tried with this

Comment: @BabulPatel If you say something is "not working", always provide the code you tried, and the error message and expected and actual output. Paste `println("Hello, world!".split(" ")[0])` into the `main` function at https://try.kotlinlang.org/#/Examples/Hello,%20world!/Simplest%20version/Simplest%20version.kt and see it print `Hello,` as desired.

Comment: this function doen't split the string. It actually returns the string as it is. @Thomas

Comment: Then I must conclude that the character in your string is not a space.

Answer (score 2):

Kotlin tries to resolve some issues that Java's `String` library has. For instance, Kotlin tries to be more explicit.

As a result, the [`split`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.text/split.html) method takes a normal `String` and does not use it as a regex internally:

```
"hello world".split("\\s")[0] //no match
"hello world".split(" ")[0] // => "hello"
```

To explicitly use the overloaded `split` function that actually takes a regex, the `toRegex()` extension can be used (`inline fun String.toRegex(): Regex (source)`):

```
"hello world".split("\\s".toRegex())[0]// => "hello"
```

The following shows another example of Kotlin resolving the confusing `String::replaceAll` method:

[image]

Taken from a KotlinConf [presentation of Svetlana Isakova](https://youtu.be/Uizh2WlJtnk), co-author of “Kotlin in Action”

Answer (score 2):

Single delimiter

```
 val splittedStringList = "123.345-80A".split(".")
 println(splittedStringList[0])
```

Several delimiters

```
 println("123.345-80A".split(".", "-"))
```

Using regex

```
 println("123.345-80A".split("\\.|-".toRegex()))
```

Try Kotlin [Online](https://try.kotlinlang.org/)

Answer (score 1):

Simply use **value.split("\s".toRegex())**

1.Splits and iterates all items

```
value.split("\\s".toRegex()).forEach { item ->
    //use item 
}
```

2.Spits and use first item

```
value.split("\\s".toRegex()).first()
```

3.Spits and use last item

```
value.split("\\s".toRegex()).last()
```